# Manipulate textarea value during "get" without later writing

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, textarea, return-value

OK, if the question seems confusing, it may be because it might be a bit silly/stupid.

Trying to write a jQ plug that might allow a `<textarea />`'s value to be manipulated on every call to *get* it, but doesn't change what the user sees.

The general idea is this:

- I have a webpage with a short `<form />` with a `<textarea />` in it.
- I call the plugin to it `onload`.
- The user types "`Bob`".
- ***Without*** manipulation to the `ajax` or `form submit`, the value that will be submitted with the form is "`1.) Bob`" instead of just "`Bob`".
- However, the user never see's it say anything other than "`Bob`"

And if the form confuses you, then leave it out of the example idea. It's not important, submit isn't even important. The general idea is simple. On call of either `ele.value` or `$(ele).val()`, the value is manipulated without further JavaScript code being needed and without the user seeing any change at all.

I've looked at possibly making use of `__proto__`, but haven't found a working manipulation that didn't show up as a method property (bleh!). So I've also looked over `jQuery.hooks` and `jQuery.fn.val` to possibly make manipulations to the jQuery lib, since this will be a jQ plug, but I've yet to come up with a decent way to edit that without making some sort of error, in general, a half dozen scoping issues.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?:

```
(function ($) {
  var originalVal = $.fn.val;
  $.fn.val = function(value) {
   if (typeof value != 'undefined') {
     // setter invoked, do processing
   }
return ('1.) ')+(originalVal.call(this, value));
};
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: eh close, that still looks like it would lead to another scoping issue, but i'll try something like that in a bit. I suppose I could scope original call to another property of the library, but then ... i dunno, i'll try it in a bit, thanks for the reply.